# In Chakra UI's Text component how to add a ternary to a Responsive Style?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

Learning Chakra and trying to figure out how based on a breakpoint and a prop to style a `textAlign` in a [`Text`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/text/usage) component.

Attempt:

```
<Text textStyle={'someStyle'} textAlign={{ base: 'center', md: {{foo ? 'left' : 'center'}} }}>
  {props.content}
</Text>
```

the equivalent to this in Styled Components would be:

```
const FooHeading = styled.h3`
  text-align: ${({ foo }) => (foo ? `left` : 'center')};
  @media only screen and (max-width: ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.md}) {
    text-align: center;
  }
`
```

In Chakra UI only, without Styled Components, how could I write my text style to either `left` or `center` based on a prop in the responsive style? If there is another approach in Chakra I haven't read about I'm for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research was able to resolve my issue with [`useBreakpointValue`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/hooks/use-breakpoint-value) hooks:

```
const textAlign = useBreakpointValue(
  { base: 'center', md: foo ? 'left' : 'center' },
  { ssr: true }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

you do not need a hook, you can use the attributes of chakra components

```
 <Text textStyle={'someStyle'} textAlign={{ base: 'center', md: foo ? 'left' : 'center' }}>
          {props.content}
    </Text>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**